# simple html dom duplicate entry in mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, dom

i'have problem when using simple html dom

my question is..

i want grabbing content from other website

but when i'm insert to db he is duplicate data or content

and how there was not duplicate data or entry

this for my code

```html
include "simple_html_dom.php";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html = file_get_html('http://example/');


$items = $html->find('div[class=thumb-box latest-entries],div[class=thumb-box latest-entries no-margin]');  
$nomor=1;
// loop into each li element
//echo"<h1>class margin</h1>";
foreach($items as $i => $post) {
    // get the img
    $img = $post->find('img', 0)->src;

    // get the post's url       
    $url = $post->find('a', 0)->href;

    // get the title
    $title = $post->find('h2[class=article-heading]a', 1)->plaintext;

    // another way to get the title
   // $title2 = $post->find('div[article-text]', 0)->plaintext;

    // get the description
    $desc = $post->find('p[class=article-text]', 0)->plaintext;

    //get date
    $date = $post->find('span[class=date]', 0)->plaintext;

    //get comment
    $comment = $post->find('span[class=comment]', 0)->plaintext;

    //get view
    $view = $post->find('span[class=view]', 0)->plaintext;

    // Print all

   if($title != "" && $url !="" && $img !="" && $desc !="" && $date !="" && $comment !="" && $view !="")
    {
   echo "<h1>$nomor</h1>
            Title   :$title<br>
           Image    :$img<br>
           Url      :$url<br>
           Description :$desc<br>
           Date     :$date<br>
           Comment  :$comment<br>
           View     :$view<br>";
           $gambar =$img; 
           $link   =$url;
    echo "<hr/>";
    }
    $nomor++;
$display=mysql_query("select * from homepage where title='$title' && url='$url' && image='$img'");
if(mysql_num_rows($display)>0)  
{
echo"<b style='color:red;'>title and url has Registered in database</b>";
}
else
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO homepage (title,image,url,description,date,comment,view)values('$title','$gambar','$link','$desc','$date','$comment','$view')")or die("".mysql_error());
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you checked with phpmyadmin for the content? It may have been added to database, but your $display query might not work properly, so it will always have zero rows => is trying to add new entries to database when they are already added.

Comment: Also, which is your primary key? Is it composed of multiple atributes?

Comment: ok thanks besciualex i have checked in phpmyadmin is add new and step first i'm grabbing success but when i'm gabbing step two he is  to be duplicate entry in my db